NextJS 14 not consistently loading scripts
On NextJS 14.1.3 I am seeing some strange behavior I do not understand. When I am visiting a page that loads JS from a file the application does not pull the JS every time. Like maybe doesn't load them 1/10 loads. I am thinking it is some race condition on the script loading vs hydration but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have tried every <Script strategy="beforeInteractive | afterInteractive | lazyOnload" /> and I also tried using next/dynamic to load the specific component and it still wouldn't work. Any ideas?
Layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Script strategy="afterInteractive" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts" />
      <Script strategy="afterInteractive" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js" />
      <Script strategy="afterInteractive" src="/hs-apexcharts-helpers.js" />
      <body>
        ...
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Chart.tsx
export default function NetWorthChart() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      buildChart('#hs-sales-line-chart');
    }
  }, []);

  return ();
}

public/hs-apexcharts-helpers.js
function buildChart(...) {...}

I tried swapping the script strategies. I tried next/dynamic loading the component.

There's no need to load these scripts globally. Instead, you can install them via NPM, which will eliminate all your issues. For ApexCharts, refer to the installation guide here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/. You can do the same for Lodash: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.

@SeanW I am using a custom buildChart function that exists in the public folder. That is the main issue, that it does not load all the time. How would I fix that?

Does the script need to be in the public folder? You can almost always colocate the function/file with the rest of your code. There is rarely a good reason to put scripts in the public folder. I recommend removing the scripts from your root layout and installing them via NPM and moving the buildChart function to the same location as the rest of your code. After moving it, the buildChart function will likely need to be updated to load properly. Since we can't see the function, we can't provide specific help.
